# Calculate the mean without zero for specefic group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row, multiple-columns, mean

I have data set like this :

```
     W   X    Y    Z
A_rep1     0  15   10   2   
A_rep2     2  14    4   8
A_rep3    15   0    8  22
A_rep4    18   3    0   9
A_rep5     0  12    0  22    
B_rep1    13   0   12  80 
B_rep2    14   2   10  45
B_rep3    15  10   12  36 
B_rep4    89  18   22  78 
B_rep5     0  22   16   0
C_rep1    15   0   12   0
C_rep2    12   0   17   5
C_rep3    22   4   50  47
C_rep4     0  14    0   0 
C_rep5     0   5    4  12
```

And i want to calculate the mean of  group A only in every column but without the 0 values for example for W column  the mean i want will be just with A_rep2 A_rep3 A_rep4 (because i have 0 values in A_rep1 and A_rep5 so the result i want is new rows that contain the mean of each group like this)
And for the other groups i want to calculate the mean using all replicates

```
             W         X    Y    Z
A_rep1       0         15   10   2   
A_rep2       2         14    4   8
A_rep3      15          0    8  22
A_rep4      18          3    0   9
A_rep5       0         12    0  22    
B_rep1      13          0   12  80 
B_rep2      14          2   10  45
B_rep3      15         10   12  36 
B_rep4      89         18   22  78 
B_rep5       0         22   16   0
C_rep1      15          0   12   0
C_rep2      12          0   17   5
C_rep3      22          4   50  47
C_rep4       0         14    0   0 
C_rep5       0          5    4  12 
Mean_A      11.66
```

Please tell me if you need any other clarification of explanations

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Starting with what I'll call `quux`, which is a 4-column frame with row names:

```r
quux <- structure(list(W = c(0L, 2L, 15L, 18L, 0L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 89L, 0L, 15L, 12L, 22L, 0L, 0L), X = c(15L, 14L, 0L, 3L, 12L, 0L, 2L, 10L, 18L, 22L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 14L, 5L), Y = c(10L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 17L, 50L, 0L, 4L), Z = c(2L, 8L, 22L, 9L, 22L, 80L, 45L, 36L, 78L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 47L, 0L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A_rep1", "A_rep2", "A_rep3", "A_rep4", "A_rep5", "B_rep1", "B_rep2", "B_rep3", "B_rep4", "B_rep5", "C_rep1", "C_rep2", "C_rep3", "C_rep4", "C_rep5" ))
```

I'll suggest a dplyr solution; since dplyr and friends tend to ignore or discard row names, I'll bring those into the frame, and separate them so we have "groups":

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # separate
quux2 <- tibble::rownames_to_column(quux) %>%
  separate(rowname, into = c("group", "rep"))
quux2
#    group  rep  W  X  Y  Z
# 1      A rep1  0 15 10  2
# 2      A rep2  2 14  4  8
# 3      A rep3 15  0  8 22
# 4      A rep4 18  3  0  9
# 5      A rep5  0 12  0 22
# 6      B rep1 13  0 12 80
# 7      B rep2 14  2 10 45
# 8      B rep3 15 10 12 36
# 9      B rep4 89 18 22 78
# 10     B rep5  0 22 16  0
# 11     C rep1 15  0 12  0
# 12     C rep2 12  0 17  5
# 13     C rep3 22  4 50 47
# 14     C rep4  0 14  0  0
# 15     C rep5  0  5  4 12
```

From here, we can summarize easy enough, using `mean(.[. != 0])` as the premise of "mean without 0s":

```r
quux2 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(across(W:Z, ~ mean(.[. != 0])))
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#   group     W     X     Y     Z
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A      11.7 11     7.33  12.6
# 2 B      32.8 13    14.4   59.8
# 3 C      16.3  7.67 20.8   21.3
```

In general, I recommend against combining summaries with the original data for all cases *except* when you are combining them for inclusion in a report. After combining, any follow-on calculations should take specific efforts to not include the summary rows in whatever is being done ... which can be difficult, so I tend to keep them separate.

However, for combining for a report, we can do (notice the addition to `summarize`):

```r
quux2 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(across(W:Z, ~ mean(.[. != 0])), rep = "mean") %>%
  bind_rows(quux2, .) %>%
  arrange(group, rep == "mean", rep)
#    group  rep        W         X         Y        Z
# 1      A rep1  0.00000 15.000000 10.000000  2.00000
# 2      A rep2  2.00000 14.000000  4.000000  8.00000
# 3      A rep3 15.00000  0.000000  8.000000 22.00000
# 4      A rep4 18.00000  3.000000  0.000000  9.00000
# 5      A rep5  0.00000 12.000000  0.000000 22.00000
# 6      A mean 11.66667 11.000000  7.333333 12.60000
# 7      B rep1 13.00000  0.000000 12.000000 80.00000
# 8      B rep2 14.00000  2.000000 10.000000 45.00000
# 9      B rep3 15.00000 10.000000 12.000000 36.00000
# 10     B rep4 89.00000 18.000000 22.000000 78.00000
# 11     B rep5  0.00000 22.000000 16.000000  0.00000
# 12     B mean 32.75000 13.000000 14.400000 59.75000
# 13     C rep1 15.00000  0.000000 12.000000  0.00000
# 14     C rep2 12.00000  0.000000 17.000000  5.00000
# 15     C rep3 22.00000  4.000000 50.000000 47.00000
# 16     C rep4  0.00000 14.000000  0.000000  0.00000
# 17     C rep5  0.00000  5.000000  4.000000 12.00000
# 18     C mean 16.33333  7.666667 20.750000 21.33333
```

In the `arrange`, `rep == "mean"` will sort `FALSE` before `TRUE` (which is what we want, in order to keep `"rep#"` before `"mean"`), and the inclusion of `rep` immediately after that may not be necessary (assuming all sorts are natural) but I felt it was good to be specific there (it costs very little).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

newcols <- df %>% mutate(group=gsub('\\_\\w+','',col)) %>% mutate(across(c(W,X,Y,Z), ~ ifelse(.x==0,NA,.x))) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(W,X,Y,Z), ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .names = 'mean_{col}'), .by = group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% slice_tail(n=1) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(col=paste0('mean_',group)) %>% 
  select(col,starts_with('mean')) %>% 
  setNames(c('col','W','X','Y','Z'))


df2 <- rbind(df,newcols)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 18 × 5
   col        W     X     Y     Z
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A_rep1   0   15    10      2  
 2 A_rep2   2   14     4      8  
 3 A_rep3  15    0     8     22  
 4 A_rep4  18    3     0      9  
 5 A_rep5   0   12     0     22  
 6 B_rep1  13    0    12     80  
 7 B_rep2  14    2    10     45  
 8 B_rep3  15   10    12     36  
 9 B_rep4  89   18    22     78  
10 B_rep5   0   22    16      0  
11 C_rep1  15    0    12      0  
12 C_rep2  12    0    17      5  
13 C_rep3  22    4    50     47  
14 C_rep4   0   14     0      0  
15 C_rep5   0    5     4     12  
16 mean_A  11.7 11     7.33  12.6
17 mean_B  32.8 13    14.4   59.8
18 mean_C  16.3  7.67 20.8   21.3
```